# Click to trigger an overlay over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlay

I know how to show an overlay over an image with a mouse hover in CSS. I know how to toggle a div in JS

Now what I want is to show an overlay over an image by clicking on the image itself. I'm afraid the hover might be a bit intrusive.

[this is where I went to far](http://guillaumeb.com/demo/)

Any idea ?

I also tried full screen overlays but this is not really easy for responsivness

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code in a jsfiddle here so we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery overlay when image clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858459/jquery-overlay-when-image-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is the best solution for this, but you can solve the problem using only JavaScript too.

First of all, since you want to trigger this on click, you should get rid of your hover attributes in CSS. Currently you have the following hover:

```
.photo-img:hover .photo-caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Change it to a custom class named 'photo-caption-show', so that we'll toggle to this class on click:

```
.photo-caption-show {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Now, you need to write a function to toggle this class on click. Write the following function in JavaScript:

```
var toggleShow = function(){
    var element = document.querySelector(".photo-caption");
    element.classList.toggle("photo-caption-show");
}
```

The function above basically gets the DOM element with class photo-caption, and toggles its class.

Now the only thing left is triggering this method. You can do it through the div you want, in this case div with class a-post:

```
<div class="a-post" onclick="toggleShow()">
```

If you want to assign this method to every element with class a specific class, instead of writing onclick to each element, you can still do it with JavaScript as follows, however, JQuery is the best way to achieve it though. Put the following code after defining your toggleClass function.

```
var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("a-post");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element= elements[i];
    element.onclick = toggleClass;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works like charm !

Comment: Now do you know if i can make use of PostID classes to trigger this script ? as there will most certainly be more than one image on the same page

Comment: @GeeB , I edited the post. As far as I understood, you want to call this method whenever you click on a specific class, right? I added the solution for this, see the last part.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the idea is to be able to trigger this Javascript on all photo posts. So I believe that instead of "a-post", I should be using the class "photo-post" But then if there are several photo posts on the page will there be any conflict ? how will the JS know that i'm triggering the div on the right image if I use a general class ? That's why i'm wondering about triggering PostID