# Laravel image click overlay javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, overlay

I would like an overlay in Laravel view when a user clicks on a image an overlay appears and u can switch to next/previous image. I'm pretty new and can't really imagine how it's done (to switch views on the overlay).

I print the images in the blade file with

```
@foreach($pictures as $pic) 
<img src="\storage\pictures\{{ $pic }}"> 
@endforeach
```

I tried [Jquery overlay when image clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858459/jquery-overlay-when-image-clicked) but didn't work for me.

I can see the `.imgcontain` css in browser inspector.

I don't need a full solution just a hint what to search. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Ben, welcome to StackOverflow. I would start by googling "lightbox". A jQuery library that I often use is Colorbox for this functionality.